# creating an arraylist in a constructor with variables from another class?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to make a simplified version of Solitaire known as Elevens. I successfully made the `Card` class but I am having trouble creating a `Deck` class. The goal is to create a deck with unique cards. Sorry if this explanation isn't the best but hopefully the code samples will help:

The Card class constructor:

```
package ElevensLab;

public class Card {
    private String suit;
    private String rank;
    private int pointValue;

public Card(String cardRank, String cardSuit, int cardPointValue) {
    rank=cardRank;
    suit=cardSuit;
    pointValue=cardPointValue;
}
```

The Deck class constructor:

```
package ElevensLab;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck {
    private List<Card> cards;
    private int size;
    public Deck(String[] suits, String[] ranks, int[] values){
        ArrayList<Card> cards=new ArrayList<Card>();
        for(String suit: suits){
            for(String rank: ranks){
                for(int value: values){
                    cards.add(suit);
                }
            }
        }
        size=cards.size();
    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: You seem to be adding suits to your list of cards, for some reason instead of constructing cards and adding them to your list of cards.

Comment: Are you asking for design help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here goes:

So, you're making an `ArrayList` of `Card`. To add an item to that `ArrayList`, it must be of type `Card`, correct? So on the line in your `Deck` class `cards.add(suit)` you are adding a `String` to an `ArrayList` of type `Card`. This is giving you a compiler error, I would assume. Instead, what I would do, is actually put a `Card` constructor, inside of the `cards.add()` call. I'll show you using your code:

```
package ElevensLab;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck {
    private List<Card> cards;
    private int size;
    public Deck(String[] suits, String[] ranks, int[] values){
        ArrayList<Card> cards=new ArrayList<Card>();
        for(String suit: suits){
            for(String rank: ranks){
                for(int value: values){
                    cards.add(new Card(rank, suit, value)); //This is the line I changed
                }
            }
        }
        size=cards.size();
    }
```

This code adds a new `Card` to the `Deck` with the desired values. I hope that you find this helpful, and wish you luck!

Comment: i'm gonna break a guideline and say THANK YOU! i didn't think about actually creating a new instance of Card